# Why i cant return h1 element in reactJs onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, return

I shorten my question, but now it look really silly, my main problem is i want to return html tag, in the question i am using just a literal string,

my function is working fine as console log is working fine, 
seeing the output i understand is this, i am firing the function at the wrong place, but i am really confused about it.

**Below is my code, Please read the comment with the code, and this not the actual problem, but i dont want to dump my full code here, again main problem console.log line is working but not the return line in the function**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Event extends React.Component {

    onEdit()
    {
        console.log('it will return this'); **//This line work**
        return 'Why i am not able to return this'; **//This one is not showing** why ??

    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.onEdit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>

        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Maxwelll thanks, but i am really it should return, but i am really new can you post the answer how, because i am able to show my button in the dom why not this simple string, and i add some thing in this return statement i am able to show it onto the webpage, hope i am clear, and thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is definitely returning a string - It seems like you are very confused... You need to return jsx and trigger a re render if you expect this to appear in the DOM

here is an example of what I mean https://fiddle.jshell.net/46hbpmna/

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you make one more thing clear, first i also try to do it with set state and it work, can it work with setState, thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: what i am saying is this, that i have to use setState, than only it going to work?? otherwise it wont

Comment: ah i just google, what the state is, and it may sound silly, i already read these line, in react, react compare virtual dom with real dom and only changes the part which is necessary, and for this it uses state, after reading those lines, your answer make lot more sense specially this line """and trigger a re render if you expect this to appear in the DOM"""

Comment: Yes you should use setState. Never mutate state directly. If the presentation of your component depends on things changing put it in the components state...

Comment: thanks, no i was thinking i cant do it with out using state, if i use state i know i have to use setState, but i was thinking i can do to it with out using state, i know it silly, But thanks for the help, and specially you gave the explanation before you posted the code, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make h1 with button props by adding role, for example:

```js
_doSomething = () => {
  console.log('asd')
}
```

```html
<h1
  className="item__title"
  role="button"
  onClick={() => this._doSomething()}
>
  Your Title
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
retun ()=> your "title"
```

inside the html tag on `onClick` button.